# Can corr.test be used for any dataframe?

Tags: r, psych

I am trying to find get correlations and p-values between variables in a dataframe (`df1`) using corr.test in the psych package.  The variables in the  dataframe are all integers and there is no NAs.  But when I run the `corr.test(df1)`, there is always a error message.

```
Error in data.frame(lower = lower, r = r[lower.tri(r)], upper = upper,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 28
```

I tried to run the example (`corr.test(sat.act)`) in the psych package and there is no error.
I am new to R, can someone tell me what is wrong with the dataframe.

```
> head(df1)
  S1.pre S2.pre S1.post S2.post V1.pre V2.pre V1.post V2.post
1     21     31      25      35      7      1      19       4
2     15     26      21      29     13     11      16      14
3     18     27      23      31      8      2       3       3
4     17     31      18      39     13     11      15      14
5     15     26      16      29     26     15      32      20
6     17     28      16      28      2      4       2       7

> dput(head(df1))
structure(list(S1.pre = c(21L, 15L, 18L, 17L, 15L, 17L), S2.pre = c(31L, 
26L, 27L, 31L, 26L, 28L), S1.post = c(25L, 21L, 23L, 18L, 16L, 
16L), S2.post = c(35L, 29L, 31L, 39L, 29L, 28L), V1.pre = c(7L, 
13L, 8L, 13L, 26L, 2L), V2.pre = c(1L, 11L, 2L, 11L, 15L, 4L), 
V1.post = c(19L, 16L, 3L, 15L, 32L, 2L), V2.post = c(4L, 
14L, 3L, 14L, 20L, 7L)), .Names = c("S1.pre", "S2.pre", "S1.post", 
"S2.post", "V1.pre", "V2.pre", "V1.post", "V2.post"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

> sapply(df1, class)
S1.pre    S2.pre   S1.post   S2.post    V1.pre    V2.pre   V1.post   V2.post 
"integer" "integer" "integer" "integer" "integer" "integer" "integer" "integer"
```

Comment: can you paste the output of `dput(head(df1))`? and even the output of `sapply(df1, class)`

Comment: infominer, I have added the structure and class information above.

Comment: I'm not yet sure of the mathematical reason why, but your example dies at the `se <- 1/sqrt(n[lower.tri(n)] - 3)` line within the `corr.test()` function. At this line, `se` is assigned a value of `numeric(0)` and this causes the exception 5 lines later at `ci <- data.frame(lower = lower, r = r[lower.tri(r)], upper = upper, p = p[lower.tri(p)])`.

Answer (score 1):

I contacted William Revelle - author of the psych package and here is what he said:

*Mark,
Unfotunately you found a bug introduced into 1.4.3.
1.4.4 will go out to Cran this weekend.
In the meantime you can get the fix at http://personality-project.org/r  (choose source from other repository if you are using a mac) or
http://personality-project.org/r/src/contrib   and get the zip file if you are using a PC.
Otherwise, wait until next week.
Sorry about the problem.
It will still work as long as you have unequal number of subjects or some missing data.*